# Car stalls when ac compresser is plugged in

Tags: ac, buick

I have a 2002 buick century with a 3.1 the car stalls while driving when the ac compressor is plugged in but when I unplug it the car runs fine can anyone tell me why it would do that.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  Sounds like the compressor is having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The idle control valve could be stuck closed.  When extra load is put on the engine at idle, then the ECU would normally open the idle control valve to compensate.  If it is stuck closed, and the compressor turns on, then the engine could stall.